# Loop vars with loop_control and loop_var Ansible

Tags: loops, ansible, task

I would need to loop some vars inside an include_task.

What is currently working:

```
- include_tasks: example.yml
  loop: "{{ flowers|flatten(levels=1) }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: flower
```

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
- include_tasks: example.yml
  loop: - "{{ flowers|flatten(levels=1) }}"
        - "{{ cars|flatten(levels=1) }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: 
     - flower
     - car
```

In the example.yml, I will have 2 sections: "flowers" and "cars". In "flowers" I should trigger just "flower" var and in "cars" I should trigger just "car" var.
Is any way to achieve this using loop and loop_var?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In a loop, you can have one [*loop_var*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#defining-inner-and-outer-variable-names-with-loop-var) only. But this *loop_var* may be any data structure that fits your case. For example, given the lists

```yaml
  cars: [toyota, ford, tesla]
  flowers: [rose, gerbera, tulip]
```

you can either iterate the lists [*with_together*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/together_lookup.html#ansible-builtin-together-lookup-merges-lists-into-synchronized-list)

```yaml
    - include_tasks: example.yml
      with_together:
        - "{{ cars }}"
        - "{{ flowers }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: item_car_flower
```

, or you can [*zip*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-items-from-multiple-lists-zip-and-zip-longest) the lists on your own

```yaml
    - include_tasks: example.yml
      loop: "{{ cars|zip(flowers) }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: item_car_flower
```

In both cases, the loop variable *item_car_flower* will be a list with two items. The first one will be the car and the second one will be the flower. You can declare the below variables to simplify referencing

```yaml
  my_car: "{{ item_car_flower.0 }}"
  my_flower: "{{ item_car_flower.1 }}"
```

Test it in the included file. For example, the file below

```yaml
shell> cat example.yml
- debug:
    msg: |
      car: {{ my_car }}
      flower: {{ my_flower }}
```

gives in both cases, running on localhost, the same result

```yaml
TASK [include_tasks] **************************************************************************
included: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-393/example.yml for localhost => (item=['toyota', 'rose'])
included: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-393/example.yml for localhost => (item=['ford', 'gerbera'])
included: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-393/example.yml for localhost => (item=['tesla', 'tulip'])

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    car: toyota
    flower: rose

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    car: ford
    flower: gerbera

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    car: tesla
    flower: tulip
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    cars: [toyota, ford, tesla]
    flowers: [rose, gerbera, tulip]

    my_car: "{{ item_car_flower.0 }}"
    my_flower: "{{ item_car_flower.1 }}"

  tasks:

    - include_tasks: example.yml
      loop: "{{ cars|zip(flowers) }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: item_car_flower

    - include_tasks: example.yml
      with_together:
        - "{{ cars }}"
        - "{{ flowers }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: item_car_flower
```